# What's the term that describes our data processes

Tags: data-warehouse, etl, terminology

We provide an online subscription product that allows our users to research and analyze financial data of their interested industries. As such, we have various tools for loading data from various sources, cleansing data, procssing data, tagging data based on user interactions etc. Basically all sorts of processes and tools that deal with data manipulation.

We are looking into overhauling our these data processes, and I am trying to find the right term to call these processes, both for research purpose and for my presentation. The names I have considered so far:

- ETL - this term seems too narrowly focused on loading data. Our data processes deal with user inputs extensively too.
- Data Warehousing - this term seems too generic and broad. I am not sure if our processes are data warehousing in nature.

I am looking for a term that I can use to name or describe our processes.

Comment: For advertising purposes, you could use the term "Business data enhancement engineers"? :-) Personally, I would call what you do "(complex) data processing".

Comment: Thanks. Any suggestion on what terms I should be googling for if I want to find new tools for our processes?

Comment: Just various combinations of what you already do - etl/data warehousing/complex data processing... without knowing a bit more, I can't really be that helpful. Unless, that is, you give the tools that you're using - but tool recommendations are off-topic here (unfortunately, in my view, but there you have it). Maybe if you have (a) more specific question(s) that we could help with? Oh, and I would (slightly) revise my description of what you do - call it "complex business enhancement data processing" or "business complementation data analysis and processing" <cringe...>.

Comment: We use hand coded SQL, Python and DSL scripts currently, so no specific tools so far. We are evaluating whether to improve our DSL tool chain, or to introduce some commercial UI tools.

Comment: I would also consider Open Source if I were you - there are some pretty awesome tools/products out there! Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks. If you convert your comments into an answer I would obviously upvote you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For advertising purposes, you could use the term "Business data enhancement engineering"? :-) Personally, I would call what you do "[complex] [business] data processing".

> Thanks. Any suggestion on what terms I should be googling for if I
>   want to find new tools for our processes?

Just various combinations of what you already do - etl/data warehousing/complex data processing... without knowing a bit more, I can't really be that helpful. Unless, that is, you give the tools that you're using.

However, tool recommendations are off-topic here (unfortunately in my view, but there you have it). Maybe if you have some more specific question(s) that we could help with? You could also possibly try [software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)?

Oh, and I would (slightly) revise my comment description of what you do - call it "complex business enhancement data processing" or "business complementation data analysis and processing" (cringe...) :-).

Just a note - if you're dealing with more technical people, steer clear of the "marketing speak" - otherwise, go for it! :-)

> We use hand coded SQL, Python and DSL scripts currently, so no
>   specific tools so far. We are evaluating whether to improve our DSL
>   tool chain, or to introduce some commercial UI tools.

I would also examine the Open Source arena if I were you - there are some pretty awesome tools/products out there! Best of luck!